# No provision ios device connected

Tags: ios5, ios4, xcode3.2

I trying to test my iPhone app on real iPhone device having ios 5.0 restored recently.
Now when i connect iPhone to mac in xcode's organizer it is showing orange dot in front of device. Let me tell you that i m using xcode 3.2.6 with ios sdk 4.3 installed on Mac .

this is message i m getting in organizer.

*The version of iOS on “Apple’s iPhone” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.*

**OS Installed on Apple’s iPhone**

***5.0 (9A334)***

**Xcode Supported iOS Versions Latest**

***5.0 (9A334)***

4.3.5 (8L1)

4.3.3 (8J2)

4.3 (8F190)

4.2

4.1

4.0

4.0.2

4.0.1
3.2

3.2.2

3.2.1

here u can check that both os installed on iPhone and Xcode Supported ios versions are same.

so i searched a lot for this and i got only one answer that reboot device as well as machine i tried both but both didn't work for me.
what can be the exact solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is glitch from Apple. I had 3.2.6 and xCode 4 but then 3.2.6 I installed manually 5.0 (9A334) on the SDK Platform SDK. It will show yellow mark that does not recognizes the device.

#### Here is What I did

Launch 3.2.6 then go to the organizer. If you see the yellow mark on your iOS 5 device then open Xcode 4 and go to the organizer. From the Xcode 4 you will see the green mark. Now close Xcode 4 and Xcode 3 completely using Command + q button. Re-Launch the Xcode 3.2.6. It now changes to Green mark instead. Hope it fixes your problem.